# App falsely reports missing file

Tags: ios, screen-recording

I downloaded a git hub project, a screen recorder(ios). It said I had to also copy in Inappsettingskit, so I did. So I tried to run it on my iPod and it told me that IASKAppSettingsViewController.h and .m were missing, even though I checked, and they are there, in the correct folder. [image]

[image]

[image]

All the files are there in the correct place. The only thing I am noticing is that the files are in red text in Xcode:
[image]

Sorry that I am such a noob. Any ideas on why these errors show up?

Comment: The second screenshot is from Build phases tab => Compile sources section?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here, but chances are something went wrong when you added the files to the project. Try this.-

- Remove the files references from `Project navigator`
- From finder, make sure the physical files are inside your project folder.
- Drag the files from finder to `Project navigator`. Uncheck *copy items into destination*
- Drag the recently added files from `Project navigator` to `Build phases => Compile sources section`